# Drawing many actors takes long time in scene2d

Tags: android, libgdx, scene2d

I have a problem with drawing many actors as it takes long time when testing with desktop project and not working on my android device.

I have a play button that when clicked should show 100 level for player to choose from.

Here is my code:

```
stage = new Stage(new ScalingViewport(Scaling.fill, 800, 1280));
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("data/uiskin.json"));
Image play = new Image(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("play.png")));
stage.addActor(play);
play.addListener(new ClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
        Table container = new Table();
        stage.addActor(container);
        container.setFillParent(true);
        Table table = new Table();
        Puzzle[] puzzles = new Puzzle[100];
        for (int i=0; i<puzzles.length; i++) {
            table.padTop(60);
            table.padBottom(60);
            puzzles[i] = new Puzzle(i, false);
            if (i%6 == 0) table.row();
            table.add(puzzles[i]).pad(5);
        }
        ScrollPane scroll = new ScrollPane(table, skin);
        container.add(scroll).expand().fill().colspan(4);
    }
});
```

Here is puzzle class which simply shows a rectangle with puzzle number and if it is solved its color should be blue and if not color should be white.

```
private class Puzzle extends Actor {
        TextureRegion rect;
        BitmapFont font;
        float w,h;
        boolean solved;
        int drawNum;
        public Puzzle(int number, boolean solved) {
            rect = new TextureRegion(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("rect.png")));
            setSize(rect.getRegionWidth(), rect.getRegionHeight());
            this.drawNum = number + 1;
            this.solved = solved;
            if (solved) font = HelpingMethods.createFont(38, Color.GOLD);
            else font = HelpingMethods.createFont(38, Color.DARK_GRAY);
            GlyphLayout layout = new GlyphLayout();
            layout.setText(font, "" + this.drawNum);
            w = layout.width;
            h = layout.height;
        }

        @Override
        public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
            Color color = getColor();
            if (!solved) batch.setColor(1, 1, 1, color.a * parentAlpha);
            else batch.setColor(0, 0, 1, color.a * parentAlpha);
            font.setColor(color.r, color.g, color.b, color.a * parentAlpha);
            batch.draw(rect, getX(), getY());
            font.draw(batch, "" + drawNum, getX() + getWidth()/2 - w/2,
                    getY() + h + getHeight()/2 - h/2);
        }
    }
```

Here is `createFont()` method:

```
public static BitmapFont createFont(int size, Color color) {
        FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator
                (Gdx.files.internal("fonts/font.ttf"));
        FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter parameter =
                new FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter();

        parameter.size = size;
        parameter.color = color;
        parameter.minFilter = Texture.TextureFilter.Linear;
        parameter.magFilter = Texture.TextureFilter.Linear;
        BitmapFont font = generator.generateFont(parameter);
        return font;
    }
```

[image]

Any Solutions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that whenever the `play` is clicked, you create new 100 `Puzzle` objects. In `Puzzle` constructor you generate `BitmapFont` with `FreeTypeFontGenerator`, which is expensive operation. And you do that **100 times**. Instead, you should generate your `BitmapFont` object once (for example, when you initialize your game), and pass a reference to it to every `Puzzle` object. Also reuse `Talbe` container and `GlyphLayout` objects.

In game development in general you should avoid creating new objects, when possible, and reuse them instead. And the reason is not only it can be slow, but also, as in your case, when you create new `Puzzle` objects instead of old ones, you create a lot of work for a garbage collector, which can cause stutters.

Don't forget to dispose the `BitmapFont` object, when it's not needed anymore.

Comment: OK. This helps. In case of disposing BitmapFont after it is no longer been used, I am loading all assets using assets manager when splash screen shows then all assets are disposed when player click exit button. Is this fine ?

Comment: Yes, and you should dispose the `FreeTypeFontGenerator ` right after generating the BitmapFont. See https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gdx-freetype. An alternative way: you can load generated  BitmapFonts using AssetManager, like in this sample: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/extensions/FreeTypeFontLoaderTest.java. Note, that in this case disposing is handled by AssetManager, so you need to call only assetManager.dispose().